# How to prefill "link_to" links with given values in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `link_to` link on my Statuswebpage:

```
<%= link_to 'New Ping Check', controller: "checks", action: "new", subcategory_id: @subcategory.id, type: "PingCheck" %>
```

Everything works beside the `subcategory_id`. It just doesn't prefill the form with it, but prefilling type for example works.

I'm using `@subcategory.id` because this link is on the `#show` site of a subcategory. And if I just use `@subcategory.id` to display it on the website it appears, but somehow it just doesn't go with the `link_to` method.

My Check controller looks like this:

```
class ChecksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_check, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /checks
  # GET /checks.json
  def index
    @checks = Check.all
  end

  # GET /checks/1
  # GET /checks/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /checks/new
  def new
    @check = Check.new( type: params[:type])
  end

  # GET /checks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /checks
  # POST /checks.json
  def create
    @check = Check.new(check_params)
    @check.subcategory = @check&.subcategory

    respond_to do |format|
      if @check.save
        format.html { redirect_to check_path(@check), notice: 'Check was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @check }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @check.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /checks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /checks/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @check.update(check_params)
        byebug
        format.html { redirect_to check_path(@check), notice: 'Check was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @check }
      else
        byebug
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @check.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /checks/1
  # DELETE /checks/1.json
  def destroy
    @check.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to checks_url, notice: 'Check was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_check
      @check = Check.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def check_params
      params.require(:check).permit(:name, :subcategory_id, :type, :input)
    end
end
```

Does anyone know why this won't work?

Comment: Please do not use line numbers in your code. We can't reuse the code to test it without stripping them, which wastes our time and slows our response.

Answer (score 0):

`@check` in the `controller.new` method is being populated with the `type` attribute only. Add `subcategory_id` too and you should get the form field prefilled:

```
 class ChecksController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_check, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   # GET /checks/new
   def new
     # @subcategory = Subcategory.find(params[:subcategory_id]
     # @check = Check.new(subcategory: @subcategory, type: params[:type])

     @check = Check.new(subcategory_id: params[:subcategory_id], type: params[:type])
   end  
 end
```

The form rendered with new method should be object backed, something like:

```
<%= form_for(@check) do |f| %> 
 <%= f.hidden :subcategory_id %>
<% end %>
```